# I took Pre Calc II and Calculus at community colllege. When I transferred, they accepted my calculus credit but says I need finite math?

Tags: mathematics, communication, transfer-student, required-course

The prerequisite for the Calculus class that they accepted was the Finite Math. They accepted my Calculus class with an A. My precalc II and calculus class should suffice the Finite math, right?

Comment: Probably not, but it depends on the content of the precalc class.

Comment: Read your university's course catalog.

Comment: You say that the finite math was a prerequisite for calculus, so presumably you have already successfully completed a finite math course. So: did you present the paperwork for the finite math to the college in the same way that you did for calculus? If so: what reason did they give for not accepting it?

Answer (score 7):

Sorry no.  Finite Mathematics is quite different from the earlier courses. It is required for a reason.

The thinking patterns are not the same. That is, I think, the most important point. Continuous and discrete math require different thought structures. If you don't get a good grounding in both then you limit yourself.

Note that Finite Math as a prerequisite for Calculus is (or was, at least) relatively rare. And in some places that do it, the FM course might be too elementary for future needs.

But the important point is that for some majors, especially math and computing, a solid course in finite math is essential. It is useful both in theory and applications.

Comment: At some colleges/universities, the "finite math course" is essentially a minimal-algebra distribution requirement for weak math students majoring in something requiring almost no math competence (i.e. essentially a "math appreciation" course), but this is fairly rare, and in a large majority of places "finite math" is as you describe. Thus, I agree, and the OP's situation is very likely different from that [of my wife's situation](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/158810/what-do-us-universities-mean-when-they-mention-anything-above-the-calculus-cou/158826#comment424711_158826).

Answer (score 1):

General requirements, core curricula, and degree plans all vary from university to university. For the sake of accreditation, there are common patterns (e.g., at least one first year composition course, at least one math course), but the exact courses required or the prerequisites built in may differ in unexpected ways. When transferring, it is always important to look at both catalogs and anticipate potential issues.

It sounds like you're in a situation where you've taken math courses, the course credits do transfer, but what you took is not directly equivalent to an additional requirement, Finite Mathematics. Usually, this means you have to take that course at the new university, even if it's technically a prerequisite for a course you now have credit for.

Occasionally, if the title and content of the course you took are close to a course at the new university (e.g. "British Literature to 1660" and "British Literature 1") and an automated system rejected equivalency, you can appeal to a university registrar with the syllabus and have them review whether the course is worth direct credit. That said, I agree with Buffy and doubt they would treat Pre-Calculus II and Finite Mathematics as equivalent.